# Error creating virtual device in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, virtual-device-manager

Yesterday, I installed Android Studio's latest version on Ubuntu. Everything ran fine, until I ran the "Hello World!" program. It asked me to create a  virtual device. While creating the device, it shows me an error that the AVD manager cannot find a system image. This makes no sense since I have already installed the latest SDK (API level 25, Android 7.1.1). I downloaded the system image from the AVD manager itself, but to no avail.
Can someone help me sort the damn thing out? I switched from Windows to Linux due to the plethora of problems with Android Studio on Windows. But the thing's bugging once again. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Have you click the "Download" in "Release Name" column? If you have, may you upload another updated screen shot, and also post what error it is.

Comment: I did it already. But the error keeps popping again and again.

Comment: But did it downloaded?

Comment: Yes. I was very careful with the installation. Further, I have the sdk installed. I have the folder in front of me.